# Call two functions asynchronous in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous

I have two functions:

1. `getDataLocal()` - which read file from disk and process it and return array
2. `getDataFromApi()` - which call api, process response and return data as array

Finally I do `array_merge` this two functions results.
It is possible execute them asynchronous with some reactPHP, amphp etc?